# Anime: giant crater in Japan, and a main character who can steal others' powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's an anime where there is a giant crater in Japan, and everyone in it has strange powers, and the main character can steal these powers to become stronger.  I think the main character had white hair? And sunglasses? And lived in a church?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/K?from=Anime.ProjectK?

Answer (score 6):

## [Needless](https://myanimelist.net/anime/6030/Needless) (2009)

A war has left craters which are known as Black Spots. People eventually start living in it and some of them even manifest special powers called Fragments. They call these people "Needless".

The main character is called Adam Blade. He's a "priest" who lives in a church together with Eve and Gido. Adam has white spiky hair and wears black sunglasses. Adam's power is that he can copy techniques from all the other Needless and use them as he sees fit.

A picture of Eve and Adam Blade:

[image: A picture of Eve and Adam Blade]